# How Do I Paste A Path Into Netbeans With Proper Formatting?

Tags: path, text-formatting, netbeans, escape-characters, escape-sequences

every time I past a file's path into Netbeans (for example, C:\programs\test.txt) I always have to add in the escape characters so that Netbeans understand the path.

So, I will paste

```
"C:\programs\test.txt"
```

And I will have to manually change it to

```
"C:\\programs\\test.txt"
```

Is there a way to make Netbeans automatically format paths like this?

Thanks guys

Comment: This seems like it may be possible, since you can apparently [script Netbeans to access clipboard data](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/view-clipboard-copy-to-clipboard-from-netbeans-ide). But besides likely being somewhat involved, I am not certain that level of Java coding would be considered on-topic for Super User. With that in mind, unrelated to Netbeans, would you be interested in a solution using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) where you could press a hotkey to replace \ with \\ in the current clipboard contents (i.e. before pasting)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I guess Autohotkey could work, but to be honest it's not really worth the effot. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

---

*Disclaimer: Not a Netbeans solution (unfortunately).*

---

> I guess Autohotkey could work, but to be honest it's not really worth the effort.

In [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), to do a simple replacement to "double" the number of `\` characters in an item path string via hotkey is relatively easy:

```
; Turn all single backslashes (\) in the current 
; clipboard item path into double backslashes (\\)
; using e.g. F4.

F4::StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, \, \\, All
```

If you mean to install AutoHotkey or to create a more complex script, I understand.

---

**File/Folder Paths**

You should be able to simply "Copy" a file as normal and, with the AutoHotkey script above, get a string path to the file after pressing e.g. `F4`. However, a few notes:

- This may take a couple seconds, so extra quick fingers might cause minor issues when pasting.
- The direct hotkey method (above) creates strings without quotes e.g.:

  ```
  C:\\example\\path with spaces\\file.ext
  ```
- If you have any trouble copying a file or folder path normally or need the path to be quoted, you should be able to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + `Right-Click` to display a `Copy as path` option in Windows. After selecting this option and using e.g. `F4`, the copied path would be similar to:

  ```
  "C:\\example\\path with spaces\\file.ext"
  ```

---

*References*

[Clipboard - AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm)